# Typescript generices incorrectly deals with partial

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

With typescript 3.7.2 , I have an error with the following function:

```js
function updateWithPartial <T,P extends Partial<T>, K extends keyof P> ( obj: T, part: P, key: K ) {
    return obj[key]=part[key]
}
```

hence , if key is keyof Partial , it must be a keyof T 
Do you see what I am missing ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case, `key` is not `keyof Partial<T>` - its type extends `keyof P`, where `P` *extends* `Partial<T>`. `P` can possibly have more/different keys than `T`, so `key` cannot be used as property for `T` here.

Assuming, you don't want to add new properties to `T`, there is no need to have type parameter `P`, as it can be inferred from `T` itself. Here are two solutions, dependent on whether you want `obj` to get `undefined` prop values from `part` or not:

```
// no undefined values assigned from part
function updateWithPartial<T, K extends keyof T>(obj: T, part: Partial<T>, key: K) {
  if (part[key] === undefined) throw new Error() // throw or do something else...
  return obj[key] = part[key] as T[K] // help compiler to understand, part[key] must be defined here
}

// possible undefined values assigned from part
function updatePartialWithPartial<T, K extends keyof T>(obj: Partial<T>, part: Partial<T>, key: K) {
  return obj[key] = part[key]
}
```

OK, some tests:

```
declare const foo: { a: string }

const res = updateWithPartial(foo, { a: "bar" }, "a") // string 
const res2 = updatePartialWithPartial(foo, { a: "bar" }, "a") // string | undefined
const res22 = updatePartialWithPartial(foo, {}, "a") // string | undefined
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=16&ssc=75&pln=12&pc=1#code/PTAEEsDNQFVAHATge3gU0QFwJ6gG4CGANgK5oDOo5AFsUaAHbKagBGaoJDAJmpOAzTcAsAChIXAMaZwyBp3jcCmNAHVwmagAUCWcMQA8MADSgA0qDQAPFT0oBrNNmTQYAPgAUyVgCsAXLCm8LqYATp6hu6mjtgBZgCUoADeYqAQ0B7BWADaMQC6oAC8xZw8fAJCiZooAO6MaHUAoogoiB6JIKDIiKDcyFTIALZomgIA5pZE5GgAdHOpoIgjJIjy3j65TgWFCCGb2AUElDDZZgWd1GhE8KCSQ-DgRBigmP1cvIjkmAQ8QXv5oEGJC+bA4vH4gm4oEuSzEAF8xGJOlBYAgUOgsLhCKQKLcfqDSuCKiJxFIZHIFEoVOEZMR1JoafoiEZTBZrLZuA4nC5YJ51mEQkyjG4-lgBRFmVFQDE4okUqI0ktMCs1r59ttdjl8vDEaJeJIiLoOHcGCDIMhkAEkqACAEvohxqAEaIxCaQUtKDsSIplGoNNpBcQPObkKZrbbQAAiVi6SNO0yRgiRjpge2O11yd0UABMRUpvsZdP9haIwYtYZtAWjsfjUaTKaomAdDAmAB9CeVIRnTSwPdnc16fdTA0R6QGJWXQ8k4Qn66BOmmW6B2+9O0IxEA)

Comment: By the way: Not knowing your concrete case, if you want `part` contain one specific defined property and have compiler enforced types instead of a run-time check, maybe [`Pick`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABCADgEwIZQKYB4AqANIgNKLYAeOYaAzogNbYCecwi+AfABRwBGAKwBcHYigwAnKCIAKMCAwKESnYk2YiSASkQBvALAAoRIgnYoICUn4CA2uoC6iALyJxU+ywdGAvkaNo2BAANpLYiBAItFCIwHBwIrqIGCLREjBgAOaIfoaRYNGm2PSuqJg43HFwxEkpiABEfJL1OcT1GPU6APRdiGkZ2Ub5hWa0AEwuyOhY2JXxNSY+bR3dvf1ZiP6GQA) is a better choice.